# How do I link my css file to my html file

Tags: html, css

I have trouble creating and linking my css file to my html file. I already wrote the code but it doesn't seem to execute any function, also i can't seem to link it to my html files

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far..

Comment: I've figured it out. thanks lal

Answer (score -1):

In order to link your css file to your html file you have to use the link attribute

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```